# Drag and Drop as Multitouch event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

I´d like to drag and drop objects in wpf solution via multitouch gesture. I get two `userControls`. I am able to drag an item from `userControl1` and place it anywhere in my application. It sounds good so far, but here is the problem:

If I move `userControl1`, the dragged and placed item is going to move with `userControl1`. That means even though I moved an item before out of `userControl1`, it is still connected to that `userControl`.

I would like to drag an item from `userControl1` and place it in `userControl2`. There shouldn´t be any data binding between the item and `userControl1` anymore, when I drag the item out of the `userControl`.

Does anybody know a suitable answer for my problem?

Comment: Seems like you are not changing the item's parent property to some other control than the UserControl when you drag it out of the UserControl. Post some code here to figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SurfaceDragDrop class in the "Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch"